# Show that the linear transformation is well defined

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was given the transformation on an exam:

$T:\mathcal{P}_2(\textbf{R})\rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2(\textbf{R})$

defined by $T(p)=((3x-1)p)'$

The first question asked something and in parenthesis stated(show that $T$ is well defined)

I attempted an answer and do not think it is correct, or what the professor intended.

I took an arbitrary polynomial $p(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2$ and $q(t)=b_0+b_1t+b_2t^2$

and showed if $p=q$ then $Tp=Tq$ but do not think this is correct.

I showed if $p=q$ then $a_0=b_0,a_1=b_1,a_2=b_2$

Showed $T(p)=3(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)+(3x-1)(a_1+2a_2x)=3(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2)+(3x-1)(b_1+2b_2x)=T(q)$

can anyone tell me if this is the correct approach, or did I do this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you should have proved was that if $p(x)\in\mathcal P_2(\mathbf R)$, then $T\bigl(p(x)\bigr)\in\mathcal P_2(\mathbf R)$ too. For instance, this would not be true if the factor $3x-1$ was replaced by $3x^2-1$.

Comment: So would you say my answer is correct or not?That was the only way I knew how to prove a function is well defined. So that was the solution I had to give

Comment: No. It is trivial that $p(x)=q(x)\implies T\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=T\bigl(q(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: so the answer is incorrect?If so how was I supposed to prove it?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect.

Comment: How would I show it is well defined?

Comment: What do you think my answer to your question was about?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what the actual question was. There was a question before and in parenthesis the professor wrote (i.e. show that T is well defined). I think it said show every polynomial gets mapped to a polynomial with degree at most 2.I can't remember exactly. I also had know Idea how to show this so I just gave the answer above.

Comment: Yes. And that is **exactly** what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: ok now I see it

Comment: so the proof would look like $T(p)=3(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)+(3x-1)(a_1+2a_2x)\in \mathcal{P}_2(\textbf{R})$ and that would be the answer

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: I added an extra answer by saying since the $rangeT=\mathcal{P}_2(\textbf{F})$,since T is surjective every polynomial in the range has degree at most 2.Would this qualify as a correct answer?

Comment: I don't know what that means. Are you saying that $T$ is surjective? That is not part of the question.

Comment: It was a multi step problem and I found T to be surjective, I then gave an alternate answer to the problem by stating since range$T=\mathcal{P}_2(\textbf{F})$ every polynomial in the range of $T$ has degree at most $2$. This would not be correct would it?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.